# Mix values from dataframes with different formats

Tags: r

I have a database with the columns: "Year", "Month", "T1",......"T31":

For example df_0 is the original format and I want to convert it in the new_df (second part)

```
id0 <- c ("Year", "Month", "T_day1", "T_day2", "T_day3", "T_day4", "T_day5")
id1 <- c ("2010", "January", 10, 5, 2,3,3)
id2 <- c ("2010", "February", 20,36,5,8,1)
id3 <- c ("2010", "March", 12,23,23,5,25)
df_0 <- rbind (id1, id2, id3)
colnames (df_0)<- id0
head(df_0)
```

I would like to create a new dataframe in which the data from T1....T31 for each month and year will join to a column with all dates for example from 1st January 2010 to 4th January 2012:

```
date<-seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-04"), by="days")
```

or join the value in a new column of a dataframe based on the values of other three columns (year, month and day):

```
year <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(date), "\\-"), "[", 1)
month <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(date), "\\-"), "[", 2)
day <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(date), "\\-"), "[", 3)
df <- cbind (year, month, day)
```

I would like to have a data frame with the information in this way:

```
Year <- rep(2010,15)
Month <- c(rep("January", 5), rep("February",5), rep("March",5))
Day<- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5))
Value <- c(10,5,2,3,3,20,36,5,8,1,12,23,23,5,25)
new_df <- cbind (Year, Month, Day, Value)
head(new_df)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. `df <- read.table(text = as.character(date), sep = '-')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is to reshape your data. One library which you can use is the `reshape2` library. Here we can use the `melt` function in the `reshape2` library:

```
melt(data.frame(df_0), id.vars=c("Year", "Month"))
```

Based on the data you have, the output would have:

```
   Year    Month variable value
1  2010  January   T_day1    10
2  2010 February   T_day1    20
3  2010    March   T_day1    12
4  2010  January   T_day2     5
5  2010 February   T_day2    36
6  2010    March   T_day2    23
7  2010  January   T_day3     2
8  2010 February   T_day3     5
9  2010    March   T_day3    23
10 2010  January   T_day4     3
11 2010 February   T_day4     8
12 2010    March   T_day4     5
13 2010  January   T_day5     3
14 2010 February   T_day5     1
15 2010    March   T_day5    25
```

Which you can then alter the variable column to the days depending on how you have formatted that column.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I generated my own test data. I used a reduced `date` vector for easier demonstration: `2010-01-01` to `2010-03-04`. In my `df_0` I generated a value for each date in my reduced date vector not including the last date, and including one additional date not in my `date` vector: `2010-03-05`. It will become clear later why I did this.

```
set.seed(1);
date <- seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'),as.Date('2010-03-04'),by='day');
df_0 <- reshape(setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(do.call(rbind,strsplit(strftime(c(date[-length(date)],as.Date('2010-03-05')),'%Y %B %d'),' ')),round(rnorm(length(date)),3))),c('Year','Month','Day','T_day')),dir='w',idvar=c('Year','Month'),timevar='Day');
attr(df_0,'reshapeWide') <- NULL;
df_0;
##    Year    Month T_day.01 T_day.02 T_day.03 T_day.04 T_day.05 T_day.06 T_day.07 T_day.08 T_day.09 T_day.10 T_day.11 T_day.12 T_day.13 T_day.14 T_day.15 T_day.16 T_day.17 T_day.18 T_day.19 T_day.20 T_day.21 T_day.22 T_day.23 T_day.24 T_day.25 T_day.26 T_day.27 T_day.28 T_day.29 T_day.30 T_day.31
## 1  2010  January   -0.626    0.184   -0.836    1.595     0.33    -0.82    0.487    0.738    0.576   -0.305    1.512     0.39   -0.621   -2.215    1.125   -0.045   -0.016    0.944    0.821    0.594    0.919    0.782    0.075   -1.989     0.62   -0.056   -0.156   -1.471   -0.478    0.418    1.359
## 32 2010 February   -0.103    0.388   -0.054   -1.377   -0.415   -0.394   -0.059      1.1    0.763   -0.165   -0.253    0.697    0.557   -0.689   -0.707    0.365    0.769   -0.112    0.881    0.398   -0.612    0.341   -1.129    1.433     1.98   -0.367   -1.044     0.57     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
## 60 2010    March   -0.135    2.402   -0.039     <NA>     0.69     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

The first half of the solution is a reshaping from wide format to long, and can be done with a single call to [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html). Additionally, I wrapped it in a call to [`na.omit()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/na.fail.html) to prevent NA values from being generated from the unavoidable NA cells in `df_0`:

```
df_1 <- na.omit(reshape(df_0,dir='l',idvar=c('Year','Month'),timevar='Day',varying=grep('^T_day\\.',names(df_0)),v.names='Value'));
rownames(df_1) <- NULL;
df_1[order(match(df_1$Month,month.name),df_1$Day),];
##    Year    Month Day  Value
## 1  2010  January   1 -0.626
## 4  2010  January   2  0.184
## 7  2010  January   3 -0.836
## 10 2010  January   4  1.595
## 12 2010  January   5   0.33
## 15 2010  January   6  -0.82
## 17 2010  January   7  0.487
## 19 2010  January   8  0.738
## 21 2010  January   9  0.576
## 23 2010  January  10 -0.305
## 25 2010  January  11  1.512
## 27 2010  January  12   0.39
## 29 2010  January  13 -0.621
## 31 2010  January  14 -2.215
## 33 2010  January  15  1.125
## 35 2010  January  16 -0.045
## 37 2010  January  17 -0.016
## 39 2010  January  18  0.944
## 41 2010  January  19  0.821
## 43 2010  January  20  0.594
## 45 2010  January  21  0.919
## 47 2010  January  22  0.782
## 49 2010  January  23  0.075
## 51 2010  January  24 -1.989
## 53 2010  January  25   0.62
## 55 2010  January  26 -0.056
## 57 2010  January  27 -0.156
## 59 2010  January  28 -1.471
## 61 2010  January  29 -0.478
## 62 2010  January  30  0.418
## 63 2010  January  31  1.359
## 2  2010 February   1 -0.103
## 5  2010 February   2  0.388
## 8  2010 February   3 -0.054
## 11 2010 February   4 -1.377
## 13 2010 February   5 -0.415
## 16 2010 February   6 -0.394
## 18 2010 February   7 -0.059
## 20 2010 February   8    1.1
## 22 2010 February   9  0.763
## 24 2010 February  10 -0.165
## 26 2010 February  11 -0.253
## 28 2010 February  12  0.697
## 30 2010 February  13  0.557
## 32 2010 February  14 -0.689
## 34 2010 February  15 -0.707
## 36 2010 February  16  0.365
## 38 2010 February  17  0.769
## 40 2010 February  18 -0.112
## 42 2010 February  19  0.881
## 44 2010 February  20  0.398
## 46 2010 February  21 -0.612
## 48 2010 February  22  0.341
## 50 2010 February  23 -1.129
## 52 2010 February  24  1.433
## 54 2010 February  25   1.98
## 56 2010 February  26 -0.367
## 58 2010 February  27 -1.044
## 60 2010 February  28   0.57
## 3  2010    March   1 -0.135
## 6  2010    March   2  2.402
## 9  2010    March   3 -0.039
## 14 2010    March   5   0.69
```

The second part of the solution requires merging the above long-format data.frame with the exact dates you stated you want in the resulting data.frame. This requires a fair amount of scaffolding code to transform the date vector into a data.frame with `Year Month Day` columns, but once that's done, you can simply call [`merge()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) with `all.x=T` to preserve every date in the date vector whether or not it was present in `df_1`, and to exclude any date in `df_1` that is not also present in the date vector:

```
df_2 <- merge(transform(setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(strftime(date,'%Y %B %d'),' '))),c('Year','Month','Day')),Day=as.integer(Day)),df_1,all.x=T);
df_2[order(match(df_2$Month,month.name),df_2$Day),];
##    Year    Month Day  Value
## 29 2010  January   1 -0.626
## 30 2010  January   2  0.184
## 31 2010  January   3 -0.836
## 32 2010  January   4  1.595
## 33 2010  January   5   0.33
## 34 2010  January   6  -0.82
## 35 2010  January   7  0.487
## 36 2010  January   8  0.738
## 37 2010  January   9  0.576
## 38 2010  January  10 -0.305
## 39 2010  January  11  1.512
## 40 2010  January  12   0.39
## 41 2010  January  13 -0.621
## 42 2010  January  14 -2.215
## 43 2010  January  15  1.125
## 44 2010  January  16 -0.045
## 45 2010  January  17 -0.016
## 46 2010  January  18  0.944
## 47 2010  January  19  0.821
## 48 2010  January  20  0.594
## 49 2010  January  21  0.919
## 50 2010  January  22  0.782
## 51 2010  January  23  0.075
## 52 2010  January  24 -1.989
## 53 2010  January  25   0.62
## 54 2010  January  26 -0.056
## 55 2010  January  27 -0.156
## 56 2010  January  28 -1.471
## 57 2010  January  29 -0.478
## 58 2010  January  30  0.418
## 59 2010  January  31  1.359
## 1  2010 February   1 -0.103
## 2  2010 February   2  0.388
## 3  2010 February   3 -0.054
## 4  2010 February   4 -1.377
## 5  2010 February   5 -0.415
## 6  2010 February   6 -0.394
## 7  2010 February   7 -0.059
## 8  2010 February   8    1.1
## 9  2010 February   9  0.763
## 10 2010 February  10 -0.165
## 11 2010 February  11 -0.253
## 12 2010 February  12  0.697
## 13 2010 February  13  0.557
## 14 2010 February  14 -0.689
## 15 2010 February  15 -0.707
## 16 2010 February  16  0.365
## 17 2010 February  17  0.769
## 18 2010 February  18 -0.112
## 19 2010 February  19  0.881
## 20 2010 February  20  0.398
## 21 2010 February  21 -0.612
## 22 2010 February  22  0.341
## 23 2010 February  23 -1.129
## 24 2010 February  24  1.433
## 25 2010 February  25   1.98
## 26 2010 February  26 -0.367
## 27 2010 February  27 -1.044
## 28 2010 February  28   0.57
## 60 2010    March   1 -0.135
## 61 2010    March   2  2.402
## 62 2010    March   3 -0.039
## 63 2010    March   4   <NA>
```

Notice how `2010-03-04` is included, even though I didn't generate a value for it in `df_0`, and `2010-03-05` is excluded, even though I did.